# From 1st step the Mac installation failed

Tags: installation

==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
Failed during: /usr/bin/git fetch --force origin

After pasted the ""/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)" prompt,

typed password, enter..

then it shows this. what's going on? any one, help!

I also downloaded the new .pkg installer. It still won't work neither.
no idea? why?